# Make a script to conditionally sum cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to make a small script in google script editor for spreadsheet that sum's cell's according to other cell. Something like:

```
IF (A2:P2)==Q2{
   SUM (A3:P3)}
```

I want to sum the cells that contains a certain character. Here a [example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vopZP_HlpEy1u8QxgIhe7Iq8UMX7s-nIYauLvidYL7o) of my question. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *need* a script for this. You are just describing [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en) which

> Returns a conditional sum across a range.

Using a copy of your sheet I got your desired result with this formula

```js
=sumif(B3:P3,"A",B4:P4)
```

Then you could use absolute cell references to make it easier to copy this down.

```js
=sumif($B$3:$P$3,"A",B4:P4)
```

**Question has changed**

Since you have changed the source sheet you are asking a related but different question. Same as before though... you don't need a script for this. You can use [COUNTIFS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en). You have two counting criteria. Count if the cell contains a letter and count if the header row contains a number. We break this up into two conditional sets.

```js
=COUNTIFs(B3:P3,Q2,B2:P2,1)
```

Q2 is the cell that contains "A" and the 1 is the header columns we are counting.

In order to move this down the row by simple drag and drop you still need to use absolute reference in the cells that are not moving. Q2 and the header row specifically.

```js
=COUNTIFs(B3:P3,$Q$2,$B$2:$P$2,1)
```

Comment: For that example sumif works, but I didn't post the question correctly, please check again.

Comment: @Luis I have update the answer. Note that you changed the question enough that it invalidated the answers. When that happens you might as well just ask another question referencing this one if you want too.

Answer (score 2):

To make the sum (row per row) of all the columns that have 'A' in the header, try in Q4:

```
=ArrayFormula(MMULT(N(IF(B3:P3="A", B4:P11,)) , transpose(N(B3:P3="A"))))
```

Change 'A' to 'B' etc.. for 'sum of all B'

If you want the result to auto-expand when new rows are added use the formula like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A4:A), MMULT(N(IF(B3:P3="A", B4:P,)) , transpose(N(B3:P3="A"))),))
```

EDIT: based on new info, I updated the formula to:

```
=ArrayFormula(MMULT((B2:P2=row(B3:B10)-2)*(B3:P10="A"), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:P2)^0)))
```

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E8rpPamtGvkrqDYTy01ekhO3D2oiqvXMSMPAi--nhyc/edit?usp=sharing)

Of course the SUMIF() proposed by Matt will equally work (and is definitely a lot simpler). To drag the formula down, use the dollar signs to 'freeze' the header row, e.g: sumif($B$3:$P$3,"A",B4:P4)).

Comment: For that example the formula works, but I didn't post the question correctly, please check again.

Comment: @Luis.. I also updated my answer. Please try to be a precise as possible when posting, because this is different then the original question.